# Set vendor-encapsulated-options (code 125) with ISC DHCPd 4.3 fails

Tags: networking, server, dhcp

I'm trying to set up my Ubuntu server 16.04 LTS Xenial to run a DHCP Server that provides the required information to a very specific device.

That device is a TV Decoder by Orange ISP (French vendor is Sagem), and it only works if the IP address is assigned by the Livebox 3 by Orange (TM) (same vendor). This restriction avoids having a different DHCP server than the one provided by Orange.

If I want to use my own DHCP server running in Ubuntu 16.04 to avoid the one running at the Livebox (it's crappy) I need to adapt my configuration.

**Bootstrap Protocol (ACK) using TV Decoder and DHCP, both from Sagem**

```
Message type: Boot Reply (2)
Hardware type: Ethernet (0x01)
Hardware address length: 6
Hops: 0
Transaction ID: 0x35139a37
Seconds elapsed: 0
Bootp flags: 0x8000, Broadcast flag (Broadcast)
Client IP address: 0.0.0.0
Your (client) IP address: 192.168.1.153
Next server IP address: 192.168.1.1
Relay agent IP address: 0.0.0.0
Client MAC address: Sagemcom_37:a1:9a (f0:82:61:37:a1:9a)
Client hardware address padding: 00000000000000000000
Server host name not given
Boot file name not given
Magic cookie: DHCP
Option: (53) DHCP Message Type (ACK)
    Length: 1
    DHCP: ACK (5)
Option: (54) DHCP Server Identifier
    Length: 4
    DHCP Server Identifier: 192.168.1.1
Option: (51) IP Address Lease Time
    Length: 4
    IP Address Lease Time: (843s) 14 minutes, 3 seconds
Option: (58) Renewal Time Value
    Length: 4
    Renewal Time Value: (421s) 7 minutes, 1 second
Option: (59) Rebinding Time Value
    Length: 4
    Rebinding Time Value: (737s) 12 minutes, 17 seconds
Option: (1) Subnet Mask
    Length: 4
    Subnet Mask: 255.255.255.0
Option: (6) Domain Name Server
    Length: 4
    Domain Name Server: 192.168.1.1
Option: (15) Domain Name
    Length: 4
    Domain Name: home
Option: (28) Broadcast Address
    Length: 4
    Broadcast Address: 192.168.1.255
Option: (3) Router
    Length: 4
    Router: 192.168.1.1
Option: (125) V-I Vendor-specific Information
    Length: 41
    Enterprise: The Broadband Forum (formerly 'ADSL Forum') (3561)
        Length: 36
        Option 125 Suboption: (4) GatewayManufacturerOUI
            Length: 6
            GatewayManufacturerOUI: 307CB2
        Option 125 Suboption: (5) GatewaySerialNumber
            Length: 15
            GatewaySerialNumber: AN16XXXXXXXXXX
        Option 125 Suboption: (6) GatewayProductClass
            Length: 9
            GatewayProductClass: Livebox 3
Option: (255) End
    Option End: 255
```

To emulate the same behavior from my own ISC DHCP Server in Ubuntu I had customized it, based on the found documentation and options.

Basically, the point is to send only to the TV decoder the following additional codes:

- Code 15: Domain name
- Code 72: Default World Wide Web Server.
- Code 125:  V-I Vendor Specific Information

Based on the ISC DHCP server documentation, the three codes exist and they could be easily sent by adding the convinient options:

- domain-name text
- www-server ip-address
- vendor-encapsulated-options string

Firstly, I tried that way:

**/etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf**

```
# Create an option namespace called orangetv
option space orangetv code width 1 length width 1;
option orangetv.GatewayManufacturerOUI code 4 = text;
option orangetv.GatewaySerialNumber code 5 = text;
option orangetv.GatewayProductclass code 6 = text;
    
# Linux Router
subnet 192.168.1.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
    option domain-name-servers 192.168.1.1;
    option broadcast-address 192.168.1.255;
    option subnet-mask 255.255.255.0;
    option routers 192.168.1.5;
    range 192.168.1.100 192.168.1.199;    
    class "sagem-vendor-classes" {
    match if substring(option vendor-class-identifier, 0, 5) = "sagem";        
    option domain-name "home";        
    option www-server 193.253.67.89;
    vendor-options-space orangetv;
    option orangetv.GatewayManufacturerOUI "307CB2";
    option orangetv.GatewaySerialNumber "AN16XXXXXXXXXXX";
    option orangetv.GatewayProductclass "Livebox 3";                       
    }
```

}

Once the new config was saved, I checked the configuration syntax by running:
sudo dhcpd -t -cf /etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf

Then, I restarted the DHCP server to reload the new config (ISC DHCP 4.3 fails sometimes to restart and reload the new config. This is somehow related to the Apache2 server. Therefore I suggest forcing it):

```
sudo -i
service dhcp restart
service isc-dhcp-server restart
service isc-dhcp-server6 restart
service apache2 restart
```

Now, I rebooted the TV Decoded, and traced the network with Wireshark again. The result of the Bootstrap ACK was

```
Message type: Boot Reply (2)
Hardware type: Ethernet (0x01)
Hardware address length: 6
Hops: 0
Transaction ID: 0x70907f18
Seconds elapsed: 0
Bootp flags: 0x8000, Broadcast flag (Broadcast)
Client IP address: 0.0.0.0
Your (client) IP address: 192.168.1.153
Next server IP address: 192.168.1.5
Relay agent IP address: 0.0.0.0
Client MAC address: Sagemcom_37:a1:9a (f0:82:61:37:a1:9a)
Client hardware address padding: 00000000000000000000
Server host name not given
Boot file name not given
Magic cookie: DHCP
Option: (53) DHCP Message Type (ACK)
    Length: 1
    DHCP: ACK (5)
Option: (54) DHCP Server Identifier
    Length: 4
    DHCP Server Identifier: 192.168.1.5
Option: (51) IP Address Lease Time
    Length: 4
    IP Address Lease Time: (843s) 14 minutes, 3 seconds
Option: (1) Subnet Mask
    Length: 4
    Subnet Mask: 255.255.255.0
Option: (3) Router
    Length: 4
    Router: 192.168.1.5
Option: (6) Domain Name Server
    Length: 4
    Domain Name Server: 192.168.1.1
Option: (15) Domain Name
    Length: 4
    Domain Name: home
Option: (28) Broadcast Address
    Length: 4
    Broadcast Address: 192.168.1.255
Option: (72) Default WWW Server
    Length: 4
    Default WWW Server: 193.253.67.89
Option: (255) End
    Option End: 255
Padding: 0000000000000000
```

As you notice, options 15 and 72 were correctly parsed by option 125 is missing. So, I tried to use the encapsulated vendor options as recommended in the manual. I Used

```
option vendor-encapsulated-options 7d:29:00:00:0d:XXXXXXXX:20:33
```

instead of the vendor-options-space method, but it failed again.

I used another workaround to send the code 125 as explained in [https://lists.isc.org/pipermail/dhcp-users/2012-July/015793.html][1]

**/etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf**

```
# Create an option namespace called orangetv
option space orangetv code width 1 length width 1;
option orangetv.GatewayManufacturerOUI code 4 = text;
option orangetv.GatewaySerialNumber code 5 = text;
option orangetv.GatewayProductclass code 6 = text;

# Package the orangetv namespace into option 125
option space vivso code width 4 length width 1;
option vivso.orangetv code 3561 = encapsulate orangetv;
option vivso.iana code 0 = string;
option op125 code 125 = encapsulate vivso;

# Linux Router
subnet 192.168.1.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
    option domain-name-servers 192.168.1.1;
    option broadcast-address 192.168.1.255;
    option subnet-mask 255.255.255.0;
    option routers 192.168.1.5;
    range 192.168.1.100 192.168.1.199;    
    class "sagem-vendor-classes" {
    match if substring(option vendor-class-identifier, 0, 5) = "sagem";        
    option domain-name "home";        
    option www-server 193.253.67.89;
    option vivso.iana 01:01:01;
    option orangetv.GatewayManufacturerOUI "307CB2";
    option orangetv.GatewaySerialNumber "AN16XXXXXXXXXXX";
    option orangetv.GatewayProductclass "Livebox 3";                       
    }
```

}

Despite these configurations, the DHCP server is not sending the code 125 win the vendor specifics.

Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
option op125 code 125 = string;
```

then insert the op125 in the subnet block as:

```
option op125 7d:29:00:00:0d:XXXXXXXX:20:33;
```

The `vendor-encapsulated-options` is option 43

Answer (score 0):

I recently had exactly the same issue. I'm using `dnsmasq` as a server (pi-hole as a base, slightly modified), but it turns out the DHCP client doesn't request option 125, so `dnsmasq` doesn't send it out.

It looks like the `dhcpd` equivalent is `dhcp-parameter-request-list`, though I am unsure how to use it. [This page](https://www.syslinux.org/old/pxe.php) provides one of the few examples I could find.

As a reference, this is the *only* config I need note the **force** in `dhcp-option-force`:

```
dhcp-host=d0:84:aa:bb:cc:dd,set:decodeur,10.1.2.3,OrangeTV
dhcp-option=tag:decodeur,option:dns-server,10.1.2.1
# Enterprise: Broadband Forum (previously 'DSL Forum') (3561)
        # Option 125 Suboption: (4) GatewayManufacturerOUI
        dhcp-option-force=tag:decodeur,vi-encap:3561,4,"A43E51"
        # Option 125 Suboption: (5) GatewaySerialNumber
        dhcp-option-force=tag:decodeur,vi-encap:3561,5,"AN16XXXXXXXXXXX"
        # Option 125 Suboption: (6) GatewayProductClass
        dhcp-option-force=tag:decodeur,vi-encap:3561,6,"Livebox 3"
```

With:

- Livebox IP: `10.1.2.1`
- Decoder IP: `10.1.2.3`
- Decoder MAC: `d0:84:aa:bb:cc`
- Livebox serial: `AN16XXXXXXXXXXX`

Roles 15 and 72 are not necessary in my case. I also have a custom search domain. However, putting the livebox as a DNS is mandatory in my case. Slightly different information can be found in multiple places on the Internet ([example](https://forums.framboise314.fr/viewtopic.php?f=57&t=5960)).

Answer (score 0):

I hope i'm not too late to answer this.

> **7d:29** means option **125** (7d) and **29** is the Length = **41**

so the string to send start at **00:00:0d:**.............